# Как по условию прервать транзакцию?

Tags: mysql

как на mysql сделать такую операцию:

```
IF (SELECT id FROM tbl_name WHERE ...)
    EXCEPTION
```

Comment: вы читали, как писать оператор if и как прерывать транзакцию?

Comment: @teran, я собственно об этом и спрашиваю, т.к. не нашел как по условию вызвать `exception`

Comment: вызвать эксепшен и откатить транзакцию это разные вещи, вам так не кажется?

Comment: @teran, я и не спрашиваю как `откатить` )) `ROLLBACK`  будет вызывать скрипт бэкенда, но для этого надо выйти из транзакции по эксепшену, который должен быть вызван по наличию/отсутствию записи в таблице

Comment: дак вот так в вопросе и напишите тогда, чтобы всем понятно было все )

Comment: [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) вам не подходит по какой то причине?

Comment: а как его дернуть при наличии записи в таблице?